# Difficulty with the tutorial "actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs"

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm following the *actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs* tutorial and I'm stuck in step *Connect to Firebase*, in "firebase use --add ", the answer is

> Error: Invalid project selection, please verify project hometeste-4a254 exists and you have access.",

but the project exist.

marcelo@cloudshell:~/smart-home-nodejs (hometeste-4a254)$ firebase list

```
┌──────────────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Name             │ Project ID / Instance │ Permissions │
├──────────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ GoogleHomeTeste  │ hometeste-4a254       │ Owner       │
└──────────────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

> marcelo@cloudshell:~/smart-home-nodejs (hometeste-4a254)$ firebase use --add hometeste-4a254
>
> Error: Invalid project selection, please verify project
>
> hometeste-4a254 exists and you have access.

Comment: Did you login to the Firebase tool with `firebase login`?

Comment: Hi @NickFelker, thanks for the reply, I really had not done it. But when I did it now gets stuck in "Waiting for authentication...". :(
I really should not be doing any steps that are not in this tutorial.

Comment: I just noticed that you're running this in Cloud Shell. You may need to run `firebase login:ci`, copy the URL to another tab, and sign in there.

Comment: Hi @NickFelker, It worked! But I had to use --no-localhost because the link it generated was for "localhost". Thanks!